# how do i have to use case by showing data from my database

Tags: php, html

This located in controller

```
case view_list:

    $view_list=view_list($name,$phone,$email,$company);
    $view=mysql_fetch_array($view_list);
    $ok=true;
    break;
```

So this is located in view

```
case view_list:
    if(isset($ok)){
?>
        <div><a href='register.php?do=view_list' >view_list</a><div>
        <div><?php echo $view['name'];  ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $view['phone'];  ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $view['email'];  ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $view['company'];  ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    break;
```

But I won't see any result when I click on view_list.

Function that I am using is stored in model.

```
function view_list($name,$email,$phone,$company){
    $q=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM detail WHERE  name="'.$name.'" AND phone="'.$phone.'" AND     email="'.$email.'" AND company="'.$company.'" ') or die(mysql_error());
    return $q;
}
```

I did include on where there wasnecessary thank you.

Comment: where is the code where your switch starts?

Comment: And what framework are you using? If you mention a model that means it's not a standalone script but part of a large package. Providing all necessary information here is vital if you want to get a good answer.